# How do I set a custom layout for NavigationIcon?

Tags: android, kotlin

We are currently using Toolbar to set up a drawer menu.

I tried to add text under the drawer menu icon, but there is no such option, so I am trying to set it up with a custom layout.

I have set the icon with setNavigationIcon(), but is there any way to set the layout instead of the drawable?

```
// MainActivity.kt

binding.navigationBar.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer)
```

```
// navigation_bar.xml

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

I want to place the title below the icon as shown in the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpQ5R.png)

I passed a custom layout in setNavigationIcon() but it is not a drawable, so an error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom layout inside `Toolbar`, In this case a simple Textview can set both `icon` and `text` as you need.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_drawer_opener"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu Title"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_drawer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I'm using ActionBarDrawerToggle, which causes problems with the related process.
Is there a corresponding fix such as setNavigationIcon()?